# Porting the python interpreter to a custom operating system

Tags: python, operating-system, porting

I am looking for resources that I could go through to port the python interpreter to a custom OS (with an implementation similar to DOS but not DOS itself). What are some important points I should keep in mind? Is the complete port of python restricted only by limitations of the OS or could there be more complexities that I might have to account for. I found http://wiki.osdev.org/Porting_Python to be useful - although, what I do need to know is if there is any documentation about all the builtin modules and how they have been ported for each OS like Windows, Unix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably have a look at Python 2.4.2 for DOS here http://www.caddit.net/pythond/downloads.php

And also check out all the other stuff ported to DOS using the DJGPP port of gcc. In addition Python has been ported to OS\2 which is DOS-like but not DOS. I believe it may have been done using a relative of the DOS DJGPP but not sure.

Hopefully, your platform will not suffer from the complex memory models of DOS.

Also, there was something called Pippy that was a Python interpreter that ran on Palm's OS around the turn of the century. There is also PyMite and TinyPy.

http://wiki.python.org/moin/EmbeddedPython has some useful leads.